# Как скрывать FloatingActionButton при скроллинге TextInputLayout?

Tags: android, kotlin

У меня во фрагменте есть FAB, которая закрывает длинный текст в TextInputLayout.
Как сделать, чтобы она скрывалась при скролле вверх и появлялась при скролле вниз?

Разметка фрагмента:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".EditFragment"
        android:background="@color/background_lilac"
        >

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/tilTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:errorEnabled="false"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            >

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/edTitle"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:selectAllOnFocus="true"
                android:imeOptions="actionNext"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:hint="@string/note_title_hint"
                />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    <ScrollView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@drawable/scrollbar"
            android:scrollbarFadeDuration="3000"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tilTitle"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            >

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/tilContent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                >

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/edContent"
                    android:gravity="top"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:hint="@string/note_content_hint"
                    />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

    </ScrollView>

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/fabSave"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_done"
            android:contentDescription="@string/note_save"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: так вроде есть шаблон с таким поведением а Android Studio

Comment: @Style-7, я шаблоны android studio уже смотрела, там fab просто есть, вроде поведения нет (у меня Hedgehog стоит)

Comment: там есть шаблон с кнопкой "отправить письмо" и текстом со "скролом", вот [еще](https://habr.com/ru/articles/270121/)

Comment: @Style-7, как называется шаблон и какая версия android studio? У меня вот так: [imgur.com/a/4vGe2eA](https://imgur.com/a/4vGe2eA)

Comment: AS 3.6.3 Scrolling Activity

Comment: https://riptutorial.com/android/example/18635/show-and-hide-floatingactionbutton-on-scroll

Comment: @Eugene, спасибо, посмотрела. Не понимаю, почему в одних тутроиалах пишут, что нужно задавать поведение в коде, а в других, что можно только через xml это сделать. Хотелось бы понять, как без кода, если это возможно.

Comment: @Style-7, спасибо, нашла. Насколько я вижу, там используется layout_collapseMode для Toolbar, а у fab поведение не задано. Переложить на мой layout не получается (

Comment: Возможно с переходом на AdroidX что-то в деталях поменялось.